# How to convert a (java) List to a (scala) ListBuffer (not Buffer) in java?

Tags: java, scala

Is there a way to convert a java.util.List to a Scala.mutable.ListBuffer ?

In JavaConverter asScalaBufferConverter return a Buffer but the method from the scala project accept only ListBuffer.

[image]

Is there a way to convert the list to a ListBuffer ? or should I check with the other team lib so they change it to buffer or list ?

Comment: Out of interest, why does the library require a `ListBuffer`? Passing mutable data structures across APIs is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez add your comment as answer?

Comment: @Tim Good point, I've talked to the other team to change it to List. That would probably fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As Luis tends to not post one-liners as answers, here is ever-so-slightly expanded answer so I can harvest his upvotes

[Scala 2.12](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/R8nTRlhsTLe9irI5lLqmRw)

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val jlist = List(1,2,3).asJava
jlist.asScala.to[ListBuffer]   // res0: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

[Scala 2.13](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mtzk3JMMT8GjMhQNFZFlSA)

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val jlist = List(1,2,3).asJava
jlist.asScala.to(ListBuffer)
```

Note Scala 2.13 introduced the following [changes](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0)

> **New [`to(Collection)`](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/Iterable.html#to%5BC1%5D(factory:scala.collection.Factory%5BA,C1%5D):C1) method**
>
> - List Replaces old `to[Collection]` method.
> - The argument is the companion object of the desired collection type, for example `.to(Vector)`.
> - The API change enables support for all collection types (including `Map`, `BitSet`, et al).

Comment: This seem to work on the command line but not in java code. asScalaBufferConverter(content.getList()).asScala().to(ListBuffer$) or code.asScalaBufferConverter(content.getList()).asScala().to(ListBuffer<String>) give a compile error in the java code.

Comment: Casting (ListBuffer<String>)asScalaBufferConverter(content.getList()).asScala() don't give a compile error but give a classcast on run time java.lang.ClassCastException: class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper cannot be cast to class scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer (scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper and scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')